# Is "a preview to such work" correct?

Tags: prepositions

I know that "of" is the most commonly used preposition after "preview."
Still, I am writing a sentence where it does not feel right:

"X published such text as a preview of Y's forthcoming book"

It feels more correct to me to write:

"X published such text as a preview to Y's forthcoming book"

Would that be correct?

Comment: Do an NGram for [**a preview * his later**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+preview+%2A+his+later&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20preview%20of%20his%20later%3B%2Cc0) and it'll treat the asterisk as a "wildcard" and show you all of the most common words that appear in that position within the passed text string. From which you'll see that ***of*** is the only preposition that occurs often enough in the cited context to show on a chart. And you can use this same method next time to find out about a *different* "preposition preference".

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Better than what I did, which is to "manually" check both terms. Still, I don't get why I found things like the often cited study, "Future of the palliative care workforce: preview to an impending crisis" and others on search engines. Doesn't it mean that there is at least some kind of tolerance for "preview to"?

Comment: Oh, absolutely! In the specific case of *He released a preview * his movie*, there isn't really a very "fixed" preposition anyway. My first comment was only intended to show that ***of*** is a perfectly good choice, not that it's the only possible choice. Other prepositions aren't common enough to show on NGrams, but there are plenty of written instances of [*preview **to** the film*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22preview+to+the+film%22) and [*preview **for** the film*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22preview+for+the+film%22), for example. And they're at least "okay".

Comment: All right, I get it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't correct.

"A view *to*..." introduces a statement of intention or purpose, for example, "he went to the store with a view to purchasing something".

A "preview" is obviously an advanced viewing *of* something, so to use it with the preposition "to" is incorrect, and sounds like you have confused the use with the expression above.

Answer (score 0):

The first variant feels more correct to me.

However, I would suggest another alternative altogether:

> X published a preview of Y's forthcoming book

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help